# C++ std::find() unexpected behavior when addressing a Class function returning a vector

Tags: c++, function, class

I'va a theory question. I've a class `Patient` in which I've a function that returns a vector of the class itself `Patient.getVars()`

```cpp
class Patient {
  #... rest of class ...
  std::vector<std::string> vVar;
  public :
    void addVar( std::string var )
    {
      vVar.push_back(var);
    }
    std::vector<std::string> getVars()
    {
       return vVar;
    };
  #... rest of class ...
}
```

I noticed that if I check with `std::find()` for an element of the vector `vVar` calling the class function:

```cpp
if ( std::find ( vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars().begin(), vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars().end(), var_name ) == vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars().end() ) {
# .... rest of code ....
```

It tells me that is **PRESENT** when it's actually **ABSENT**, and vice-versa.

Otherwise, if I copy the vector and find on it:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vPzVars = vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars();
if ( std::find ( vPzVars.begin(), vPzVars.end(), var_name ) == vPzVars.end() ) {
# .... rest of code ....
```

It behave as expected! This is very important for me to find out... Any clue?

PS: I address the `Patient` object by its position `[ posPz ]` cause `vPatientClass` is a vector of `Patient` class objects.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: `getVars()` returns a copy each time you call it. Not only that could be slow, it also causes the problem you're seeing. In `std::find ( vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars().begin(), vPatientClass[ posPz ].getVars().end(), var_name )` you pass iterators to two *different* vectors (two copies of the same vector), which is not allowed. Return a reference: `const std::vector<std::string> &getVars() const`

Comment: So I could just make the vector public and access it directly...right?

Comment: Or return it by reference

Comment: You can keep the copy, but just have `auto patients = vPatientClass[posPz].getVars();` beforehand

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sounds like an answer!

Comment: @NathanOliver, just adding : `std::vector<std::string> getVars() { return &vVar;};` ?

Comment: @cccnrc No, change the return type: `const std::vector<std::string> &getVars() const { return vVar; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getVars` member is returning a *copy* of the internal vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> getVars()
{
   return vVar;
};
```

So in your problematic `std::find` invocation, you are calling `Patient::getVars()` 3 times and getting 3 different copies of the vector. While the values will be the same, the iterators you get from `begin()` and `end()` are NOT compatible with each other. You can return your vector by reference instead:

```
const std::vector<std::string>& getVars() const
{
   return vVar;
};
```